# Unable to deep clone

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to make a copy of an object.

Following that, I plan to modify values within the copy but these

modifications should not affect the original object.

Thus I want to make a clone and presently using lodash's deepClone.

But it keeps throwing the following error:

> Error!Object(...) is not a function

There is no function within my object. It is just in following structure.

They are just key values where values are either strings or booleans.

```
const myOriginalObject {
    mainKey : {
        isMobile: true,
        data: {
            id: '',
            header: '',
            flag: '',
            desc1: '',
            desc2: '',
            logo: {
                src: '',
                alt: '',
            },
            img: {
                src: '',
                alt: '',
            },
        }
    }
}
```

Just to test it out created a random object as follows.

And even this throws same error.

```
  const myOriginalObject = {
    b: '',
    c: ''
  }
```

This is the implementation to deep copy. myOriginalObject can be either one of above objects.

```
import { cloneDeep } from 'lodash/cloneDeep';

const myClone = cloneDeep(myOriginalObject);
```

What am I doing wrong? Pls advice. Thanks.

UPDATE:

My lodash version from package.json

```
"lodash": "^4.17.20",
```

Error:

> render had an error: TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Comment: It's not saying there's a function in your object. Please include the *complete* error and the lodash portion of your package.json. This is how `cloneDeep` is used, so either the error is coming from somewhere else or there's a packaging/import/export issue. (Noting that your first example isn't valid JS.)

Comment: @DaveNewton Updated the version above. Error wise there isn't much else. Just says render had an error and the previously mentioned error.

Comment: `import { cloneDeep } from 'lodash/cloneDeep'` -> `import cloneDeep from 'lodash/cloneDeep'` since you're directly importing, no need for importing individual parts. Your other option is `import { cloneDeep } from 'lodash'` but I'd advise to use the first one.

Comment: @VLAZ Not sure what kinda magic going on. Switching to import cloneDeep from 'lodash' works now. Thank you.

Comment: @Fllappy `import { cloneDeep }` will import the *named export* called `cloneDeep`.  `import cloneDeep` will import the *default export* and just give it the `cloneDeep` name. The `'lodash/cloneDeep'` module only exports a single function as a default export. That's why using `import { cloneDeep }` doesn't work - there is no *named* export called that. The `'lodash/someFunction'` packages are there to allow you to only import things one by one. `import { cloneDeep } from 'lodash'` will load the *entire* lodash module and then only get `cloneDeep` out of it. It's wasteful.

Comment: @VLAZ Get your point. Amended.

Comment: It's actually how the lodash and its namespace has been exported. The better way of using it in so that the linter/compilet doesn't shout is. First you import the lodash `_` namespace and then use the cloneDeep function.

```
import _ from 'lodash';

const a = { name: 'John Doe', address : { street: 'Grand road' } };
const b = _.deepClone(a);
```

Answer (score -2):

try with this

```
const myOriginalObject {
    mainKey : {
        isMobile: true,
        data: {
            id: '',
            header: '',
            flag: '',
            desc1: '',
            desc2: '',
            logo: {
                src: '',
                alt: '',
            },
            img: {
                src: '',
                alt: '',
            },
        }
    }
}

const newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myOriginalObject));
```

Now make any changes to newObj it will not reflect to myOriginalObject;